# How to write into an existing document

Tags: apex, xml, document

i have uploaded a doc and trying to access it from my Apex code. But now i need to insert some information into my doc. How can i do this i tried it by using

```
 my code 

  public class readXmldemo{

 public Document doc {get;set;}
 public XmlStreamReader reader {get; set;}
 public String xmlbody {get;set;}
 public readXmldemo(){

    doc = [select id, Name, body, url from Document WHERE Name = 'XMLFileDemo'];
    system.debug('Document after SOQL ' + doc);

    //system.debug('Get the elemets form XML file ' + reader.getEventType());
    xmlbody = (doc.body).tostring();
    system.debug('XML body contaion '+ xmlbody  );

    String soapNS = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
    String xsi = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
    String serviceNS = 'http://www.myservice.com/services/MyService/';

    Dom.Document dom_doc = new Dom.Document();
    dom_doc.load(xmlbody);
    system.debug('XML body in Dom Doc ' + dom_doc );

    //Retrieve the root element for this document.
    Dom.XMLNode SalesforceObjecet = dom_doc.getRootElement(); 
    Dom.XMLNode ObjectNameSF = SalesforceObjecet.getChildElements()[0];

    string fieldName = ''; 
    string objecetName = '' ;   

    ObjectNameSF.addChildElement('field6',null, null).addTextNode('AccountField_FromApex');
    ObjectNameSF.addChildElement('csv6', null, null).addTextNode('csvField_FromApex'); 
    update doc ;

    /*
    XmlStreamWriter writer = new XmlStreamWriter();    
    writer.writeStartDocument('utf-8', '1.0');        
    writer.writeStartElement(null, 'Salesforce', null);
    writer.writeStartElement(null, 'object', null); 
    writer.writeCharacters('AccountObject_FromApex');

    writer.writeStartElement(null, 'field6', null);
    writer.writeCharacters('AccountField_FromApex');
    writer.writeEndElement();   

    writer.writeStartElement(null, 'csv6', null);
    writer.writeCharacters('csvField_FromApex');
    writer.writeEndElement();  

    writer.writeEndElement();   
    writer.writeEndElement(); 

    system.debug('Written xml file ' +writer.getXmlString());    
    writer.close(); 
    */

    for(Dom.XMLNode child : SalesforceObjecet.getChildElements()) {           
            objecetName = child.getText();
            system.debug('Object Name in XML field  ' + objecetName );

            for(Dom.XMLNode subchild : child.getChildElements()) {
                fieldName = subchild.getText();
                system.debug('Filed Name in XML field  ' + fieldName );
            }
    } 




    //system.debug('Doc to xml string ' + doc.toXmlString());


}
}
```

By doing this way the value is getting inserting into the doc which i am trying yo get display on my Vf page. But the actual doc is not getting updated which i have uploaded can any body guide me what i am missing out. Please guide me.

Comment: So your saying that when you do dom_doc.toXmlString() your new elements are not present?

Comment: yes, I can only see it when i run my code but not able to save.

Comment: Can you extend your answer to include the code doing the saving?

Comment: hi, Andrew i have updated my question by adding my code.

Comment: Try inserting the following code before your last system.debug : `doc.body = doc.body + writer.getXmlString(); update doc;`

Comment: i am getting error when i added update. DML currently not allowed 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Comment: Do you have Edit permissions for Documents and also permissions to the folder where this document is stored?

Comment: You cannot run any DML inside a Visualforce page constructor. Move the logic to a separate function, and call it as an action method on the page.